# ¿Como mostrar Hora Con minutos y segundos cambiantes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Le estoy asignando el valor de la fecha y hora a un campo de texto utilizando javascript,sin embargo en vez de que sea un valor estático en el campo, me gustaría que la hora se actualizara constantemente(por un tema de consultas en la base de datos)¿Como podría hacer eso?

Actualmente estoy mostrando la fecha y hora de esta forma

```
var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
document.getElementById("fecha_registro").value = today;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Actualización**

Lo realice nuevamente desde cero y en una pagina completamente en blanco, copia el código tal cual como esta y debería funcionar. si no te funciona así, revisa tus parámetros y/o configuraciones:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reloj con segundero dinamico</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript"> 

    function mueveReloj(){ 
        momentoActual = new Date() 
        hora = momentoActual.getHours() 
        minuto = momentoActual.getMinutes() 
        segundo = momentoActual.getSeconds() 

        horaImprimible = hora + " : " + minuto + " : " + segundo 

        document.form_reloj.reloj.value = horaImprimible 

        //La función se tendrá que llamar así misma para que sea dinámica, 
        //de esta forma:

        setTimeout(mueveReloj,1000)
    }

</script> 

</head> 

<body onload="mueveReloj()"> 

    <form name="form_reloj"> 
        <input type="text" name="reloj" size="10"> 
    </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, el setTimeout("mueveReloj()",1000) debe de ir dentro de la función javascript verdad?

Comment: No me esta mostrando la hora :C

Comment: Ya hice los cambios y olvide cargarlo con la pagina asi que lo puse en onload dentro del body, me avisas cualquier cosa, ya lo probé, así que debería de funcionare.

Comment: Vi los cambios, pero a un así solo me muestra el textboxt. Gracias por responder

Comment: Revisa ahora, por que lo tengo corriendo justo ahora en una pagina de prueba y otra de produccion, hice un ultimo cambio

Comment: mmm tal vez el problema se deba al onload="mueveReloj()" que esta en el body, el body lo estoy cargando dinamicamente desde otro archivo php . EL onload="mueveReloj()" lo agregue en un div, sin embargo no carga si lo hago. ¿No puede agregarse en otro lado que no sea el body?

Comment: Estoy Cargando desde la etiqueta section hasta el fin del body solamente en esa pagina

Comment: Dame un momento salgo de la oficina y cuando tenga tiempo reviso pero el codigo funciona revisa las etiquetas del scrip

Comment: Te lo agradezco

Comment: Ya he actualizado el código nuevamente, prueba de esta forma, no creo que tengas inconveniente alguno, si no, me avisas de todas formas, dale y me cuentas cualquier cosa, si te funciona no se te olvide aceptar la respuesta. suerte!

Comment: Hola pregunte en la pagina inglesa usando tu ejemplo y me dijeron que deberia de quedar de esta forma :                                                                                var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

function new_clock(){ 
  clock = new Date() ;
  hour =   clock.getHours(); 
  minutes = clock.getMinutes() ;
  seconds = clock.getSeconds() ;
  print_clock= today + " " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  $("#fecha_registro").val(print_clock);
  setInterval(new_clock, 1000);

}

new_clock();

Comment: Sin  embargo esto produce que las respuestas del modulo sean mucho más lentas, ejemplo si quiero seleccionar una opción de un select, como que se pega unos segundos,¿ Sabes por que produce? Estoy guardando el resultado en la base de datos, ya que los segundos hacen una gran diferencia a la hora de consultar  los registros

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68533/discussion-between-andersson-viveros-martinez-and-cristianox21).

Answer (score 1):

Lo deje de esta forma, así no se vuelve lento el modulo

```
 var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

 function new_clock(){ 

 clock = new Date() 
 hour =   clock.getHours() 
 minutes = clock.getMinutes() 
 seconds = clock.getSeconds() 

 print_clock = today + " " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds 

 document.subida.fecha_registro.value = print_clock
 setTimeout(new_clock, 1000)
 }

 setTimeout(new_clock, 1000)
```

HTML

```
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group"  onload="new_clock()">

       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fecha_registro" name="fecha_registro"   >   
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Me alegra que lo hayas solucionado, para ayudar a otras personas, acepta tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Lo are, aunque debo de esperar un día :P Gracias

Comment: @CristianOx21 https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer